# WPF. Using Grid. Cell's size is changed

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

```
<Window x:Class="DemoWPF.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" >
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="2">Button</Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

After starting I see window:

[image]

If I will change size of the window slightly I see next window:

[image]

Why is size of the button changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably (but arguable) a bug in WPF. You are declaring your grid as having three equal-size rows. The button takes up only one row.

When the resize is fired, WPF squishes your button since it should only be showing in the first row. It *should* look like this on start-up:

[image]

You can fix this by specifying a `MinHeight` on your Window:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" MinHeight="100">
```